# Google Contact API Error

Tags: google-contacts-api

I am using Google Contact API for accessing my contacts through java. I am using my gmail account for this. My account has Two-way password authentication. So I wrote one sample program to display the title. But I am getting error like

> Exception in thread "main"
>   com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService$InvalidCredentialsException:
>   Invalid credentials   at
>   com.google.gdata.client.GoogleAuthTokenFactory.getAuthException(GoogleAuthTokenFactory.java:600)
>     at
>   com.google.gdata.client.GoogleAuthTokenFactory.getAuthToken(GoogleAuthTokenFactory.java:500)
>     at
>   com.google.gdata.client.GoogleAuthTokenFactory.setUserCredentials(GoogleAuthTokenFactory.java:346)
>     at
>   com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.setUserCredentials(GoogleService.java:362)
>     at
>   com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.setUserCredentials(GoogleService.java:317)
>     at
>   com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.setUserCredentials(GoogleService.java:301)
>     at com.contact.manager.Create.createContact(Create.java:15)     at
>   com.contact.manager.Create.main(Create.java:26)

My Code :

```
public class Create {

    public void createContact() throws IOException, ServiceException {
        ContactsService contactsService = new ContactsService(
                "mine-MyProduct-3");
        contactsService.setUserCredentials(username,
                password);
        URL feedUrl = new URL(
                "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/{EmailID}/full");
        ContactFeed resultedFeed = contactsService.getFeed(feedUrl,
                ContactFeed.class);
        System.out.println(resultedFeed.getTitle().getPlainText());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ServiceException {
        Create create = new Create();
        create.createContact();
    }
}
```

1. I am using Two step authentication for my account at that time I am getting error like this.
2. While using normal account (I mean one step authentication) I am not getting any kind of error.

Is there any special way to do authentication while having two step authentication.
Can you please help on this. I stuck over here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Google clearly states in the 2-step documentation, you cannot use your regular password for API access.

Instead, you should use OAuth 2.
Alternatively, you could create an app-specific password.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply. I didn't understand what is the app-specific password. How can I create that password. Could you please provide how can I authenticate using OAuth2 authentication. If you provide any sample code its more helpful to me.

Comment: Can you provide me sample code for solve the Contact API error. I have checked above link but didn't understand.

Comment: @Shailesh: What don't you understand?

Comment: @SLaks: I have used this code for fetch contact , but where can I pass client Id for OAuth String url = "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full";
   ContactsService service = new ContactsService("ContactsSample");
   try {
    service.setUserCredentials(username, pwd);
   } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }

Answer (score 1):

Just try this! I hope it will help a little. When an API request fails, an HTTP will return in 4xx or 5xx response code that generically identifies the failure as well as an XML response that provides more specific information about the errors that caused the failure.